# When there is decimal number in N[], how can ensure digits more than machine precision?

Tags: number-representation, output-formatting

We know that

```
 N[3/7,100]
```

will keep 100 digits after decimal point.

But

```
N[3.1/7,100]
```

will Keep only machine precision fewer than 100.

So, if I need 100 dicimal digits, I should convert **N[3.1/7,100]** to **N[31/70,100]**. However, in some long codes, to keep 100 decimal digits, it is not relistic to check every **N[]** whether it contains decimal point.

Is there any way to keep 100 decimal digits no matter of **3.1** or **31**?

Comment: How about `N[Rationalize[3.1/7, 0], 100]`?

Comment: @user64494 Change every **N[]** in the note? It is large work.

Comment: @Nasser How to determine the length after decimal point? **SetAccuracy** can't.

Comment: @Y.zeng: The button `Edit/Find` of Menu  can be used to this end: you replace `N[` by `N[Rationalize[` and `,100]` by `,0],100]`.

Comment: @user64494 Your way is one of the methods to solve this problem.

Comment: Enclose your expression by Rationalize: Rationalize[ expression]

Comment: @DanielHuber Is there any other ways to keep the length after the decimal point?

Comment: Try e.g.: N[Rationalize[expression], 100]

Comment: @DanielHuber **N[Rationalize[10000/2], 5]** only contains one digit after the decimal point.

Comment: You are confusing Accuracy and Precision. N[..,n] gives Precision of n, not Accuracy of n

Comment: @DanielHuber Okay, I will ask another question about this. Thanks.

Comment: How about '3.1\`100/7`